# Axios is getting called but not in my Event Handler

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a weird situation where my AXIOS ajax call is being made even though the call is being made in the event handler. The flow is as follows.

I have a material-ui drawer that has a listitem that swaps a component on my main page. This component has a submit button that makes an Axios call to a REST API but it's being called on the event handler from the ListItem not when I click submit.

Here is some code:

```
handleSubmit() {
    // var apiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:4000/api/";
    const apiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:8000/";
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    const self = this;
    const payload = {
        "to": this.state.to + " " + this.state.toTime,
        "from": this.state.from + " " +this.state.fromTime
    };
    axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    axios.post(apiBaseUrl + 'api/SaveSchedule/', payload, { headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'} } )
        .then ( (response)  => {
            if (response.status == 200) { }
            else if (response.status == 400) {
                console.log("");
            } else {
                console.log(" ");
                alert(" ");
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            if (error.response.status==400){
                alert("Check your credentials at arlo.netgear.com. Invalid email or password. ");
                console.log("Data:" + error.response.data);
                console.log("Status: " + error.response.status);
                console.log("Headers: " + error.response.headers);
                console.log("Error: "+ error);
            } else if (error.response) {
            } else if (error.request) {
                // The request was made but no response was received
                // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
                // http.ClientRequest in node.js
                console.log(error.request);
            }
        });
}
```

**RENDER:**

```
render() {
    const { from, to } = this.state;
    const modifiers = { start: from, end: to };
    return (
        <div className="InputFromTo">
            ...
            <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
            <TextField
                id="starttime-placeholder"
                label="Start Time:"
                placeholder="Enter Start Time"
                margin="normal"
                />
            <TextField
                id="endtime-placeholder"
                label="End Time"
                placeholder="Enter End Time"
                margin="normal"
                /><br/>
                <Button variant="raised" color="primary" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Save Schedule</Button>
            </form>
            ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

**EDITED**
Additionally, I have a ListItem on my Drawer. This is where the call is being made.

```
  handleListSelect(event) {
    this.props.onDrawerSelect(event.target.value);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ListItem button>
                <ListItemIcon>
                    <ScheduleIcon/>
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Scheduler" onClick={this.handleListSelect}/>
            </ListItem>
```

I am wondering if the fact that am using the props handler causes this to send some kind of event to my children (the actual component which has that event)?

Comment: could you elaborate on what you mean when you say: "even though the call is being made in the event handler"?

Comment: Sure. The only place where the axios call is made is in my handleSubmit event. For some reason, when the component is loaded this gets called asynchronously and outside of the event handler. This shouldn't happen. Not sure why.

Comment: FYI - you can set axios.defaults.baseURL = apiBaseURL instead of adding it to your urlString manually. Are you creating an axios instance somewhere else? I feel like we're not going to be able to solve it just from this code. As you mentioned, it must be getting called from somewhere else (outside the event handler).

Comment: I looked and it is not getting called. Just on this one.

Comment: Why would this even get called on a component load?

Comment: It shouldn't on component load. I'm going to post an answer to clean a few things up for you. Let's see if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173152/discussion-between-axwack-and-twils0).

Answer (score 0):

This is related with how you are calling `this.props.onClick` inside your `<Button/>` component. Probably what you are doing inside `<Button/>` component is something like this `onClick={this.props.onClick()}`. By doing that, you are calling the function because of the `()`.

Instead, you can just keep passing the reference of the function `handleSubmit` by doing this `onClick={this.props.onClick}` inside the `<Button/>` component.

If you decide to wrap `handleSubmit` with an arrow function, you will be creating a new function each time the component renders. `onClick={() => this.handleSubmit()}`.

In this last escenario you will need to use the `()` to fire the function. Do it only once: either with `this.handleSubmit()` or `this.props.onClick()`, but not both.

Hope that works for you!

Comment: I'm not going to downvote or anything, but I think you should reconsider your answer Steve. Are you saying that by including onClick={this.someFunction} on a button, someFunction will be fired when that button mounts? If so, that's not correct.

Comment: I am trying by putting in the lifecycle event.

Comment: @twils0 you are probably right. I will update my answer to something I consider more accurate. Thanks!